# How to use Thebes classes in latest XULRunner sdk?

Tags: firefox, xul, xpcom, xulrunner

I have C++ code running well with XULRunner from 7 up to 11 versions:

```
    nsRefPtr<gfxWindowsSurface> targetSurface = new gfxWindowsSurface(hDC, gfxWindowsSurface::FLAG_FOR_PRINTING); 
    nsRefPtr<gfxContext> ctx = new gfxContext(targetSurface);
```

But when I tried to compile it with XULRunner 12 and later, it cause linkage errors:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall gfxContext::gfxContext(class gfxASurface *)" (??0gfxContext@@QAE@PAVgfxASurface@@@Z) 
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall gfxWindowsSurface::gfxWindowsSurface(struct HDC__ *,unsigned int)" (??0gfxWindowsSurface@@QAE@PAUHDC__@@I@Z)
```

I've make dumpbin for xul.lib and found that there are no any exports for THEBES API now. They were removed when SDK change version from 11 to 12.
Is it way to use gfxWindowsSurface and gfxContext in binary XPCOM in the latest xulrunner sdk`s?

Thanks,

Serge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant change is [bug 683891](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=683891), also see [bug 718985](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=718985) for extended discussion. It seems that allowing third parties access graphics code directly is no longer considered desirable. So the answer to your question is: no, you can no longer do this with the stock XULRunner. So you can either look for alternative ways to achieve your goal (e.g. higher level drawing surfaces like `<canvas>` as suggested in the bug) or you can create your own XULRunner build with this particular patch reverted.

Comment: This is not a good news. I really don't understand these guys. Releases of the XUL SDK are running as speed train, changes in API are sporadic and mysterious, documentation was lost in ancient times and I don know how is possible to up to date a native extension.

Comment: @SergeZ: Well, it is low-level internal API that you probably shouldn't have used in the first place...

Comment: My primary task is a make render via own HDC to record document into EMF. It works well on the FF>=11.

Comment: @SergeZ: The usualy approach if you need native code to render a screen area is an NPAPI plugin.

Comment: How it works? Do I need to use NPN_InvalidateRect +  NPP_HandleEvent for WP_PAINT? But how I can pass my own HDC into Firefox? Thanks.

Comment: @SergeZ: You are asking the wrong person, I have no experience writing plugins. You better ask a new question, this is already pretty far off from the question you asked here.